# How to extract Json data from js int html with conditional logic

Tags: javascript, html, json, api

I need to write a conditional that checked each image value and if its empty displays a stock photo 'selfie.jpg' and if it is not then display whatever is inside of it.

I know how to access it beat.officers[0].image. what I don't know is how to make the program check through the length of officers for each items image value, check if its empty and then display a photo based on the results of that check.

pls help its for a test.

[A image of the Json object I am trying to work with](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rG626.png)

```
const policeData = [
{
  beat: 
  {
    name: 'Portishead',
    latLong: ' ',
    introText: 'Contact your local policing team, find opportunities to meet the team and view or contribute to community policing priorities for your area.',
    officers: [
      {
        name: 'Trevor Dyson',
        role: 'Neighbourhood Police Team Sergeant',
        image: ''
      },
      {
        name: 'Kirsten Karcher',
        role: 'Police Community Support Officer',
        image: 'kkarcher.jpg'
      },
      {
        name: 'Bill Hoover',
        role: 'Police Community Support Officer',
        image: ''
      },
      {
        name: 'Andrew Henry',
        role: 'Partnership Support Officer',
        image: ''
      }
    ],
    priorities: [
      {
        title: 'Road Safety Week',
        updated: '18 November 2019',
        path: '/road-safety-week/'
      },
      {
        title: 'Community SpeedWatch',
        updated: '14 August 2019',
        path: '/community-speedwatch/'
      },
      {
        title: 'Mopeds using footpaths and speeding vehicles',
        updated: '04 September 2019',
        path: '/mopeds-using-footpaths-and-speeding-vehicles/'
      }
    ]
  }
}];
```

So here is my template which is functional. As you can see though its not dynamic and I tried to input the conditional as a function with an if statement but its just not working. I did consider trying the turnery (condition : if yes : if no) but I struggled with that too.

Some of the image values are empty you see? Ultimately, I am trying to make it go through each object and check its image value and then run the conditional.

```
function kk(police) {
    officers = police.beat.officers.length;

    return `
    <div class=person>
        <img class="pol-photo" src = "${photoO(police.beat.officers[0])}"
        <h2 class ="pol-name">${police.beat.officers[1].name}</h2>
        <p> ${police.beat.officers[1].role}</p>
    </div>
    `
}


function photoO(pol) {
    if (pol == '' ) {
        return 'officer-profile.jpg'
    }   else {
        return 'kkarcher.jpg'
    }   
    }
```

Comment: 1) If it's for a test, shouldn't you be doing it yourself?  2) Are you asking about Java or JavaScript (they are very different, you know)? Please avoid posting text as an image as no one can copy and parse the text out of an image, at least not without considerable effort. 5) Also, please show your own code attempt with your question.

Comment: changes have been made sir/mam

Comment: Java? JavaScript? I still wonder if you're using the wrong tag as I see no Java code, and you don't want to attract the wrong experts. I know very little about JavaScript myself.

Comment: ahhh I see, no I believe you are right. my mistake, it is javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the functions from below to get the correct output. One function will return the HTML for just one officer while the other will return the HTML of all of them. You can test it below.

```js
const policeData = [
{
  beat: 
  {
    name: 'Portishead',
    latLong: ' ',
    introText: 'Contact your local policing team, find opportunities to meet the team and view or contribute to community policing priorities for your area.',
    officers: [
      {
        name: 'Trevor Dyson',
        role: 'Neighbourhood Police Team Sergeant',
        image: ''
      },
      {
        name: 'Kirsten Karcher',
        role: 'Police Community Support Officer',
        image: 'kkarcher.jpg'
      },
      {
        name: 'Bill Hoover',
        role: 'Police Community Support Officer',
        image: ''
      },
      {
        name: 'Andrew Henry',
        role: 'Partnership Support Officer',
        image: ''
      }
    ],
    priorities: [
      {
        title: 'Road Safety Week',
        updated: '18 November 2019',
        path: '/road-safety-week/'
      },
      {
        title: 'Community SpeedWatch',
        updated: '14 August 2019',
        path: '/community-speedwatch/'
      },
      {
        title: 'Mopeds using footpaths and speeding vehicles',
        updated: '04 September 2019',
        path: '/mopeds-using-footpaths-and-speeding-vehicles/'
      }
    ]
  }
}];

// helper function to check if value is empty
function existsAndNotEmpty(value) {
  if (typeof value != 'undefined' && value.length > 0) {
      return true;
  }
  return false;
}


function getOfficerHTML(officer) {
    let result = "";

    if( existsAndNotEmpty(officer.image) ) {
      result += '<img class="pol-photo" src = "' + officer.image + '" />';
    } else {
      result += '<img class="pol-photo" src = "officer-profile.jpg" />';
    }

    if( existsAndNotEmpty(officer.name) ) {
      result += '<h2 class ="pol-name">' + officer.name + '</h2>';
    } else {
      result += '<h2 class ="pol-name">Unknown officer</h2>';
    }

    if( existsAndNotEmpty(officer.role) ) {
      result += '<p>' + officer.role + '</p>';
    } else {
      result += '<p>Unknown role</p>';
    }

    return result;
}

function getAllOfficerHTML() {
  let result = "";
  let officerLength = policeData[0].beat.officers.length;
  let officers = policeData[0].beat.officers;

  for(var i=0; i < officerLength; i++){
    result += getOfficerHTML(officers[i]);
  }

  return result;
}

// Now you can use it like this to print a single officer
var singleOfficer = getOfficerHTML(policeData[0].beat.officers[1]);
console.log(singleOfficer);

// or like this to get all ooficers at once
var allOfficers = getAllOfficerHTML();
console.log(allOfficers);
```

Comment: Thank you, this makes so much sense.

Comment: @o97 You're welcome. If this answer solved your question please consider accepting it as the correct answer / upvoting. Thanks